# Two-level sorting in Excel with one as Number and second as date

Tags: excel, sorting

So I have a sheet with almost 50 columns and I have to sort them according to only two columns, say, `ID` and `DATE`, where `ID` is a number.

What I want is the data should be sorted first by `ID`(ascending) and than by `DATE` (descending, newer date first).

Problem is, whatever I am trying the data is sorted by Excel for `DATE` column in *ascending* order , i.e, earlier date is coming first not in *descending*.

Can anyone suggest me more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Check value type

Check the type of the date column. It has to be a number to be sorted correctly.
The safest version-independent check:

1. select an unused column in your table (in the following assumung that your the date coloumn is 'B', the data rows starting in row 2)
2. put the formula "=TYPE(B2)" in that cell.
3. If the result is 1, your Date value is a number (at least in that row)
   If the result is 2, your Date value is a string that might behave unexpectedly when you sort.

Solution II: Assure the values being numbers
(Caution: Befeor starting, make sure that you havbe backed up your data)

1. Put the number 1 into an empty cell somwhere on your sheet
2. Copy the cell (important! not only the formula)
3. select all fields in your data column
4. Hit the right Mouse key, select 'insert contents'
5. Select the options 'values' and 'multiply'
   If the 'multiply' option is not available immediately within the 'insert contents'-submenu when you hit the right mouse button (depends on the excel version) select the 'Insert Contents...' sub-sub-Menu to get the complete insert values-dalog.
6. Hit 'OK'
7. If (some of) your date values are turned into 5-digit figures, they were in deed strings. Don't panic! Change the number format of the entire date coloumn to the date format of your liking.

Generally:

In the excel sort dialog, you can always select the sorting order. If the data are OK, the result is also.